# Daisychaining 2 DisplayPort 1.2 monitors causes both to turn off

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, displayport, daisychaining

I have two Dell U2414H monitors for my desktop. They worked great for years. A while back both monitors did not turn on after restarting from a Windows 10 update. Having an additional laptop, I lived with it for the time.

Fast forward to August last year. I built a new computer and attempted to use these monitors. During the build I only used one and it worked. Post-build I plugged in both monitors via the daisy-chain to the second one and instantly they both entered power-saving mode and turned off, refusing to turn back on.

Switching monitors did nothing. Using HDMI on one and DP on the other also causes the problem to manifest.

Using only one monitor works either with HDMI or DP.

What would cause this type of behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into purchasing a new set...Apparently this is a known issue that the monitors/DP ports/daisy-chaining just stop working:

- [Amazon 1-star reviews](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00GTV05XG)
- [Newegg reviews](https://www.newegg.com/dell-u2414h-23-8-full-hd/p/N82E16824260174?Description=Dell%20U2414H&cm_re=Dell_U2414H-_-24-260-174-_-Product&quicklink=true)

Long story short. The monitors are not great in long-term quality and their DP ports will die within 2 years.