# One of the Display Port connected to Intel Graphics not working

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I have 2 Display Port and an HDMI Port on my laptop and an HDMI Port.

1. Mini Display Port 1.3 (using NVIDIA graphics). It's working
2. Mini Display Port 1.2 (using Intel HD Graphics). It's not working
3. HDMI Port (using NVIDIA Graphics). It's working.

Both Graphics drivers are up-to-date and working.

Note: I am using HDMI to mini Display port convertor. One monitor is using an HDMI port, second is using the Nvidia display port using the adapter. I want to buy a 3rd monitor and connect it to the remaining Display Port, but want to resolve this issue before ordering it.

Does buying a monitor which natively supports mini display port will solve the issue? How do I check to be sure since the monitor store here doesn't have return policy.

Note: I see some CPU usage in system process when I use the Intel Graphics Port. WPA says it's related to igdkmd64.dll which is part of Intel Graphics.

Comment: It's not working more than likely due to the fact it's disabled due to the dGPU you have installed.

Comment: Check to make sure it's not [the monitors themselves](https://superuser.com/questions/1610386/daisychaining-2-displayport-1-2-monitors-causes-both-to-turn-off). I had an issue like this and it turned out to be that particular monitor brand's DP ports just die unexpectedly.

Comment: Are these 3 ports in 2 different physical locations, or do they all come from one single 'backplate'. My 3-port GPUs have an either/or structure so any two will work, but not a third.

Comment: @Ramhound I forgot the term for this technology, but my laptop supports both active graphics card at the same time.

Comment: @Casey I have tried 2 monitors. Same issue in both brands

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry for the confusion. It's a laptop and all 3 ports are adjacent and connected to motherboard.

Comment: Then I'd check with the manufacturer [my last comment should have said 'many' not 'my', of course]

Comment: Try going into the motherboard firmware and see if there is an option to initialize the Intel graphics first before the nVidia, Then try the monitors again and see if you get different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figure out the issue.

The Display Port connected to Intel HD Graphics doesn't support HDMI to mini DP adapters. You need to have a monitor which natively supports Display Port for it to work.